# Creating 9 columns in 3 rows of text CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create 9 columns in 3 rows of text in CSS. Each column is supposed to have a headline. Can you help me out a bit please. This is my text for creating the 9 columns but I cannot get the rows done.

```
    .descpText {

    -webkit-column-count: 9; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 9; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 9;

    -webkit-column-gap: 40px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-gap: 40px; /* Firefox */
    column-gap: 40px;

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Should look like this

```
    Headline 1             Headline 4
    blalalalalalla           blalallalalallala
    blallalalalaalal        balalalallalalala

    Headline 2             Headline 5
    blalalalalallala       blalalalalalalala
    blalalalalalalla       blalalalalalallaala

    Headline 3
    blalalalallala            and so on.....
    blalalalallala
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, works flawlessly, not sure what is wrong with yours.

```
.descpText {

-webkit-column-count: 9; 
-moz-column-count: 9; 
column-count: 9;

-webkit-column-gap: 40px; 
-moz-column-gap: 40px; 
column-gap: 40px;

}
```

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/VvyRmb

I have placed the headlines for you there, but this layout is suboptimal, especially with headline block elements. I would rather do this with flexbox.